# UpgradeWizard.aspx error when upgrading from DNN 9.0.1 to DNN 9.0.2

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I am currently trying to upgrade my DNN application from version 9.0.1 to version 9.0.2. I have downloaded the upgrade.zip for version 9.0.2 from https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform I then exported the content and copied it to my website folder. When I then go to my website (which only runs locally) I get a DNN error without any text or information. It says `DNN Error` only on a grey background in the browser. Using the developer tools I could see that the following error is displayed in the console:

```
GET http://local.sylaender.me/Portals/_default/default.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) - UpgradeWizard.aspx:8
```

I have looked at the `UpgradeWizard.aspx` file. It refers to a `default.css` which is located in the folder `/Resources/Shared/stylesheets/dnndefault/7.0.0/`. I copied it and pasted it into the directory `/Portals/_default/`. The error in the console of the developer tools did not come with it any more, but with the call of the page `DNN Error` still shows without any information. In the console of the developer tools there are no more errors to see.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the EventLog table in the database to see if you're getting a specific error

```
select top 15 * from eventlog order by logcreatedate desc

select * from exceptions
```

I think that's the query to use, see if that gets you any additional info that is helpful

Comment: So the first query gives me besides hash values the following useful information: `LogTypeKey: PAGE_LOAD_EXCEPTION; LogConfigID: 6; LogProperties: some xml`. Everything else is not very useful. The second query gives the following useful information: `Message: Access to the path "C:\inetpub\sylaender.me\Portals\0-System\Cache\Pages\" was denied;`

Comment: `StackTrace: at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost) at DotNetNuke.Services.ModuleCache.FileProvider.GetCacheFolder(Int32 portalId) at DotNetNuke.Services.ModuleCache.FileProvider.PurgeExpiredItems(Int32 portalId) at DotNetNuke.Services.ModuleCache.PurgeModuleCache.DoWork(); Source: mscorlib`.

Sorry but everything didn't fit in the first comment.